# Where is fluentd stdout?

Tags: logging, fluentd

I'm trying to debug a fluentd config file by reading the logs in stdout. This is the relevant part of my conf:

```
<match mytag>
    @type stdout
</match>
```

Where can I read the stdout? I am running fluentd as td-agent. I searched for the process ID with:

```
ps aux | grep td-agent
```

Then, using the PID, I run

```
lsof -p${PID}
```

Which gave me, among other things, this line:

```
ruby    4887 td-agent    1w      CHR    1,3      0t0       7 /dev/nul
```

I also tried this:

```
sudo ls -la /proc/${PID}/fd/1
```

Which gave me this:

```
l-wx------ 1 td-agent td-agent 64 Oct 12 22:11 /proc/4887/fd/1 -> /dev/null
```

Does this means stdout is being discarded? How can I change this behavior so I can look at fluentd output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of stdout tag goes to same log where td-agent's log is.

By default you can see at /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.log